# Cannot connect to remote ipython notebook server

Tags: jupyter-notebook

This is really weird. I have a notebook server running remotely and can connect to it successfully until yesterday.

I still can connect to the notebook server using `localhost` or `[ip]` on the remote server. But when trying from a remote PC it is always timeout.

I `netstat -antop | grep :port` and saw jupyter listening on both localhost and any ip. Also I tried to `tcpdump` what the remote server got on port and can see web request coming in from my remote PC and retried for two times. But the `ipython notebook` doesn't get any requests (telling from the debug string in `--debug` mode).

Any clue why this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have ruled out all other possible causes, it is probably a firewall between you and the remote host blocking the port.

Comment: But I can see the packets arriving on the remote host, I guess that means no firewall?

Comment: Thanks you are right @Kim, I looked back in command history and see some dude set `ufw` default to `deny`. Should have known `tcpdump` operates in front of firewall. +1.